# shiny radio buttons broken

Tags: r, radio-button, shiny

Radio buttons are broken for me in shiny-0.12.1/mime-0.3. The following code works with an older version shiny-0.11.1/mime-0.2 but not with the newer version (input$dist and input$n return empty strings). An example below is based on http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html but the select menu is modified to radio buttons.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>HTML UI</h1>
  <p>
    <label>Distribution type:</label><br />
   <input type="radio" name="dist" value="norm" checked="checked" />Normal<br>
   <input type="radio" name="dist" value="unif" />Uniform<br>
   <input type="radio" name="dist" value="lnor" />Log-normal<br>
   <input type="radio" name="dist" value="exp" />Exponential<br>
 </p>
  <p>
   <label>Number of observations:</label><br />
   <input type="number" name="n" value="500" min="1" max="1000" />
 </p>
  <pre id="summary" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
  <div id="plot" class="shiny-plot-output"
      style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
  <div id="table" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
# Define server logic for random distribution application
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 # Reactive expression to generate the requested distribution. This is
 # called whenever the inputs change. The output renderers defined
 # below then all used the value computed from this expression
 data <- reactive({
     dist <- switch(input$dist,
                                   norm = rnorm,
                                   unif = runif,
                                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                                   exp = rexp,
                                   rnorm)
     dist(input$n)
   })
 # Generate a plot of the data. Also uses the inputs to build the
 # plot label. Note that the dependencies on both the inputs and
 # the data reactive expression are both tracked, and all expressions
 # are called in the sequence implied by the dependency graph
 output$plot <- renderPlot({
     dist <- input$dist
     n <- input$n

     hist(data(),
               main=paste('r', dist, '(', n, ')', sep=''))
   })
 # Generate a summary of the data
 output$summary <- renderPrint({
     summary(data())
   })
 # Generate an HTML table view of the data
 output$table <- renderTable({
     data.frame(x=data())
   })
})
```

Comment: For the record, this was probably cross-posted at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shiny-discuss/m16suDzhEMk/070MLrmedvMJ

Answer (score 1):

Just add in one more div

```
  <div id="dist" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container">
<label>Distribution type:</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="dist" value="norm" checked="checked" />Normal<br>
<input type="radio" name="dist" value="unif" />Uniform<br>
<input type="radio" name="dist" value="lnor" />Log-normal<br>
<input type="radio" name="dist" value="exp" />Exponential<br>
  </div>
```